# Makefile clean all target is called twice when explicitly invoked

Tags: makefile

I am still figuring out why in the below Makefile, when I execute it in the command like **make clean all** it runs twice the "clean all" target part?

```
FLAGS = -g -Wall -Wextra -Werror

a.out : check.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $< 

clean all:
    rm -rf *.o *.out *.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

The target "clean all:" is equivalent to:

```
clean:
        rm -rf *.o *.out *.txt
all:
        rm -rf *.o *.out *.txt
```

You can't have spaces in target names, each word would be considered a target. So when you do `make clean all`, make thinks you want to build target "clean" and target "all" and so you have 2 targets being executed. It does look like a mistake in the makefile since having all doing the same as clean is weird.